# Oracle SQL Developer Third Party Migration Issue

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-migration

I have installed 11g on window 7 
using SQL Developer of 11g I am migrating the SQL server 2008 database to Oracle 11g
Migration> Quick Migration
selecting Source Connection >Target Connection> Repository
AND
verify
it generate Errors:

---

Locating source plugin FAILED
Checking multi-schema roles FAILED Role 'RESOURCE' is not granted with admin option

---

I have granted the all required permission to the User But it still generating the same error.

Please Help

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates you should do this:

```
Grant RESOURCE to 'your_user' with GRANT OPTION;
```

Have you done that?  Show us the roles the user has been granted

Verify that you can connect to the SQL server database with that user and then, to the Oracle database with that user.  This [link](http://thinkoracle.blogspot.in/2010/09/using-oracle-sql-developer-with-ms-sql.html) may assist.

Comment: grant resource to migrations with admin option;
grant create role to migrations with admin option;
grant alter any trigger to migrations with admin option;
grant create user to migrations with admin option;
grant create session to migrations;

Comment: I have granted all the  required permission to the User But it's still generating the same error.

Comment: @AbhinavJain - do you get the exact same message now, or is it now complaining about role SESSION? You didn't grant that one with admin option, were you supposed to?